# Para que serve o "?." em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operadores

Bom dia! Estava vendo um trecho de código e me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
if (status === 401 && data?.error?.extensions?.challenge === 'Bearer') {
    delete api.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
    removeStoredUser();
    RootNavigation.navigate(routes.authentication);
}
```

Qual a finalidade exatamente do **?.** ?

Pelo que deduzi seria um tipo de verificação se existe o data e depois o error e assim sucessivamente, estou correto?

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente a utilização do ponto de interrogação antes do operador "." funciona como um "failback" para caso essa propriedade não exista no seu objeto, evitando o uso de:

```
if(data && data.error){ 
     return data.error
} else {
     return undefined
}
```

Ele cria essa validação para caso a propriedade do seu objeto exista ele retorna ela, caso não retorna undefined. Assim seu código não quebra.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado :D